# How to enable other programs to modify existing program

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

I am in the works of creating a python program similar to [this](https://code.google.com/p/pybotwar/)
. Anyway what i want to do is have users be able to modify there own programs but i need help understanding how this works. I have looked through the source code and am confused where this happens even if someone could just point me towards that that would be very helpful. I know that the programs will not be sandboxed but that is not something im worried about at the moment. If you could point me in any direction that would be great! Thank you!

Comment: I think there's an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here—your real question is not the question you've actually asked. What you really want to know is how to run some other Python script in a separate Python interpreter, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "robot programs" are just stored as plain text files.

There's a general-purpose text editor in [editor.py](https://code.google.com/p/pybotwar/source/browse/editor.py). When you open a robot in a given view, e.g., the Qt4 view in [qt4view.py](https://code.google.com/p/pybotwar/source/browse/qt4view.py#224), it just instantiates a text editor and hands it the robot's file. Again, the fact that the robot's file is a Python script doesn't matter; it just edits it as a text file.

The battle code, meanwhile, opens the same robot files as Python code that the text editor opens as text files. You can see this code in [game.py](https://code.google.com/p/pybotwar/source/browse/game.py#77): It just uses the `subprocess` module to run Python, passing the robot file as an argument.

Comment: Would it be possible to write a similar program without the editor.py file? As in having the user write a new robot object and then saving it to a certain folder.

Comment: @user2251164: Of course. In fact, pybotwar can also work that way if you prefer, as the documentation explains (and it looks like if you build it without PyQt4, that's the only way you can use it). If you want to write something without an editor, just don't write an editor.

Answer (score 0):

My other answer deals with what you actually asked. But I don't think it's what you really wanted to know.

You just want to know how to run some Python script, that you've got a pathname for, in a separate Python interpreter, right?

While it's possible to figure that out from the pybotwar code, there's a whole lot of extra stuff that will get in the way of understanding it—the `conf.py` file, the configurable extra flags, etc.

But the answer is simple: Use the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/subprocess.html) module, just as you would for running *any* program. In this case, the Python interpreter is the executable (usually you want [`sys.executable`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/sys.html#sys.executable), the same Python interpreter you're using), and the script you want to run as an argument. For example:

```
script_output = subprocess.check_output([sys.executable, script_path])
```

The `subprocess` documentation explains all the different options very nicely.